# A PHP pendant for Java's Throwable.addSuppressed()

Tags: php

Consider this exemplary code fragment:

```
/**
 * @throws \DomainException
 */
public function doFoo()
{
    try {
        // Do a unit of work with in a transaction.
        // This code could throw a SomeOtherException.
        // In this case the transaction should be rolled back
        // and a \DomainException should be thrown.

    } catch (SomeOtherException $e1) {
        try {
            $this->pdo->rollback();
            throw new \DomainException("Failed", 0, $e1);

        } catch (\PDOException $e2) {
            // $e2 is lost!
            throw new \DomainException("Failed even more", 0, $e1);
        }
    }
}
```

The immutable contract allows only to throw a `DomainException`.
I'm interested in the second catch block (the inner `catch (PDOException $e2)`). I could either use $e1 or $e2 as the previous exception, but not both.

I don't like that one exception got swallowed ($e2 in this case). So how could I throw the complete error informations, i.e. a \DomainException which includes $e1 and $e2? I was thinking about adding $e1 to the root of $e2 and using $e2 as previous, but PHP's `Exception` is immutable.

Edit: PDO is just an exemplary use case. I could be any other API as well where I might be interested in the stack trace of both exceptions.

Edit2: Consider this as an implementation of an interface which can't be changed.

Edit3: Java's [`Throwable.addSupressed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-) would fit here perfectly. This might help to understand the use case.

Comment: Why are you automatically throwing an exception after the `rollback()` call? What value does this add? Are you simply trying to rethrow a generic Exception as a DomainException? At a minimum you need to isolate the catch logic around the rollback from other rethrow logic that you are attempting.

Comment: There's something happening within the try block which might throw another exception than `DomainException`. In that case the transaction should be rolled back. Furthermore the contract allows only throwing a `DomainException`. The values are: No side effects, as the transaction was rolled back (consistency), plus the contract is not violated (defined behaviour).

Comment: You could subclass `\DomainException` to take both `$e1` and `$e2` as arguments?

Comment: @Kenney And what happens then with those two arguments? Assume a logger wants to print the chain of causes.

Comment: IMO you should have `doFoo()` documentation such that caller knows both a `DomainException` and `PDOException` could possibly be thrown.

Comment: @MikeBrant This is not an option. Just assume it's an implementation of an interface with zillions of usages and implementations. Can't touch this!

Comment: @MarkusM You could override getMessage() that would return `super::getMessage() . "\nAdditionaly, this went wrong:\n" . $this->e2->getMessage()`. Or you could catch the exception and display it as usual, then also display the 2nd exception. You could also issue a warning where you discard the less important exception. Stacktraces are linear, and passing 2 exceptions makes it a tree; different concept, no standard support. 
In any case you'll have to pick one for the trace, which contains the source line it was thrown from. Also, you probably don't really care for the trace of `$e2` (pdo lib?)

Comment: Btw, I'd really consider not throwing `\DomainException` wrapping `$e1`, but re-throw `$e1` (I'd use `\Exception` there to guarantee the transaction is rolled back). If the rollback succeeded, no harm done, and application logic can decide what to make of `$e1` - it should have meaning outside the function, right? Furthermore, I'd treat bugs and database errors seriously as this involves data integrity, and simply allow `\PDOException` on the `rollback` to be thrown - and handled!

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like this:

```
catch (\PDOException $e2) {
    // Probably you do even need to pass more parameters
    // to PDOException() to make it an exact "clone|brother". 
    // However, should get the concept out of it.
    $e = new \PDOException($e2->getMessage(), 0, $e1);
    throw $e;
}
```

Unfortunately you'll loose the stacktrace of `$e2` (the PDOException) in that case. To get around this, you might create custom exception with 2 additional properties like `$domainException` and `$rollbackException`. You might simply override getMessage() in that class and combine the messages of the nested exceptions to get a consistent error message in log files.

Btw, that's a good question. I'm curious what will others say.

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting approach and it seems to be the best so far. But (Sorry) now I'm missing the stacktrace of $e2. Well in my question it's probably fine, but I took PDO just as an example. But so far this approach looks promising. BTW it should be `throw new \DomainException("Failed even more", 0, $e);`

Comment: You are right, let me think about it again.. However, I don't see another *base concept*..

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch The best thing I could imagine of which would keep both stacktraces would be a customized exception class which has two addtitional properties like `$domainException` and `$rollbackException`. What do you think about that? About your issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685584/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-a-catch-block/31686021?noredirect=1#comment51314213_31685584), you might simply override `getMessage()` in that class and combine the messages of the nested exceptions.

Comment: Currently I tempt to accept that there's simply no way of handling that case in a sane way in PHP. So I'd say your approach is valid. I'm now trying to add a `Throwable::addSuppressed()` into PHP itself.

Comment: I'm also not happy with my solution - because of the missing stacktrace. But a customized exception class should at least work. What should `Throwable::addSuppressed()` do in your opinion?

Comment: The same as in Java land. I.e. `$e2` will be added as a suppressed exception to the thrown exception. `$e1` is the cause.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch I don't have much experience with Java. But as you describe it, it sounds interesting.

Comment: @MarkusM I'm pretty sure there's no way in **any** programming language except DIY. Same concepts, same linear (deterministic) thread of execution etc.. You could `fork()` and process throwing the exceptions in parallel... ;-)

Comment: I made an update on that topic as an own answer (sorry for that), because the information are to much for a comment, nor do they fit into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that indeed `finally` does everything automatically:

```
try {
    throw new Exception("A");

} finally {
    throw new Exception("B");
}
```

This would print:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'A' in /home/malkusch/tmp/test.php:4
>   Stack trace:
>
> #0 {main}
>
> Next exception 'Exception' with message 'B' in /home/malkusch>/tmp/test.php:7
>   Stack trace:
>
> #0 {main}

I didn't expect that as there's no causality between both exceptions, but that's acceptable as `Exception::getPrevious()` has no further semantic specified.

Unfortunately that is undocumented behaviour and can't be considered as stable. [Bug #68270](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68270) shows that currently no one knows what the expected behaviour should be. So it's not safe to rely on that. Let's see what the [discussion in internals](http://news.php.net/php.internals/87358) will bring.